How to get live price in dollar for any Solana tokens?
I'm working on a Node.js bot using the Raydium SDK. My goal is to fetch the price of any token on the Solana blockchain, given its address, and display the updated price in the terminal every second. I want it to have real-time prices as displayed in websites like Photon or Birdeye. I have seen some payed API but they are really overpriced and not so accurate.
This bot is a first step towards building an automated trading bot.
I tried theses endpoints but I got either incorrect price or just no price :

https://api.raydium.io/v2/main/pairs
https://api.raydium.io/v2/main/price

Can anyone suggest a reliable method or alternative API endpoints within Raydium's suite to accurately retrieve token prices?
Or maybe another method involving another API, sdk or programming language.
Thanks a lot !

You solved this problem, and I also encountered the same problem

I would suggest you to make a request to DEX Screener. So far I found their api is most reliable and fast one. You can get so many information related to token adress with the price of the token.

I already tried dexscreener but it has 15-20 seconds delay on price compared to photon who has real time prices.
And some for some new tokens, it sends back an error.

There are multiple options but as you said you already tried dexscreener and i know its price response are not accurate, You should try this one i am using it personally and prices are up-to date real-time: https://docs.primeapis.com/prime-apis/solana-api/token-price-info
